# Can xsd:sequences be nested as subsequences?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like to know if it is valid (I assume so) to have a sequence within a sequence and if so, what would be the (intended) benefit from this.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm currently try to setup an interface that outputs a tax file specific to Poland. For those interested, [here's](http://www.mf.gov.pl/documents/764034/5134536/Schemat_JPK_VAT%282%29_v1-0.xsd) the full XSD, however I just refer to the "interesting" parts here:

```
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="LpSprzedazy" type="tns:TNaturalnyJPK">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Lp. wiersza ewidencji sprzedaży VAT</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <!-- lots of other elements -->
        <xsd:element name="K_14" type="tns:TKwotowy" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Kwota netto - w tym dostawa towarów, o której mowa w art. 129 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="K_15" type="tns:TKwotowy">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Kwota netto - Dostawa towarów oraz świadczenie usług na terytorium kraju, opodatkowane stawką 5%</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="K_16" type="tns:TKwotowy">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Kwota podatku należnego - Dostawa towarów oraz świadczenie usług na terytorium kraju, opodatkowane stawką 5%</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <!-- two other sequences like the one for "K_15" and "K_16" above-->
        <xsd:element name="K_21" type="tns:TKwotowy" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Kwota netto - Wewnątrzwspólnotowa dostawa towarów</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <!-- lots of other elements -->
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="typ" use="required" fixed="G"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**My question are:**

1. Is a sequence within a sequence (without any hierarchical node like element or complex type) allowed?
2. What sense does it make to have elements `K_15` and `K_16` as an sequence. Is it because it would be allowed to omit both but not individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, `xsd:sequence` elements can be nested in XSD.
2. Yes, `K_15` and `K_16` in your shown XSD are collectively optional
   due to the `minOccurs="0"` on the parent `xsd:sequence`.

Another useful subsequence pattern is when  `maxOccurs` is greater than 1, indicating that the subsequence of elements may repeat together.